# Display player count on website from another website

Tags: json, curl, xpath

I'm trying to fetch "current / max Players" from this site:
http://rust-servers.net/server/64099/

I would like to display just the player numbers, eg. "70 / 175" on another website and have it update every time someone visits my .html page (I can change that one to .php if needed.)

How would I go about doing that in the most simple and efficient way?

I've googled the issue for some hours without any luck, I'm no closer to understanding what I would want to use to do this as everyone seems to suggest widely different methods and most seem way too verbose for the simple thing I'm trying to do - many examples fetch the data as JSON (?) with some JS/jQuery (?) and use a bit of code to find specific items in that data, define it as a variable or array and then display it later.

I've figured that the information I want can be referred to using XPath "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[9]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/strong" but that's about it. How do I proceed from there?

Thank you.

Comment: what did you try? And what is your issues?

Comment: I'm still no closer to understanding what I would want to use to do this, everyone seems to suggest widely different methods and most are outside my scope of understanding. I just refuse to believe it has to be as complicated as most examples seem to make it. I'm not trying to fetch a lot of data, sort it, define it as different variables, use those later etc., I'm just interested in grabbing something I know the XPath of and display it on another page (.html or .php)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which platform do you want to use.

If you use C#, you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net) library.

It is basically like this:

```
var webClient.DownloadString("http://rust-servers.net/server/64099/");
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[9]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[2]");

var nodeValue = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I go about implementing that on my site?